# google form redirect after submission opens redirected page within the existing page on WP/Elementor

Tags: wordpress, google-forms, elementor

I have embedded a google form on a page on my WordPress/Elementor website. I added a redirect in the google form settings/confirmation message. The redirect does not open the page correctly - it stays within the original page.
I have tried this two ways - using the WP custom HTML block and the custom HTML widget in Elementor. The problematic result is the same.
Here's an explanatory video.

https://www.loom.com/share/4990da5dcd9d40b0b30dd7c6eb2cbd3e?sid=a8e27dc1-9fb6-40f2-a26b-55ec2d7a144d

Hope someone can help with this one.

I have sought advice from Google community and they have referred me to Stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance!

Kirsty

I was expecting the link to return to the homepage of the website.

Comment: `Here's an explanatory video.` Thanks for providing the video. But please don't assume that users can/should/will watch the video to better understand your scenario or problem. ALL of this information should be included in the body of your question - your video should be a complement to this information, not a substitute for it. Would you please edit your question to ensure that all the relevant information is included in the body of your question. OTOH, I think that this question might be better directed to the WordPress site of the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/